# Import volley into Android Studio 1.3.0 project

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, android-volley

I am having trouble in importing and using the volley library in the android studio 1.3.0 project. I have followed tutorials online to import the volley from git into the project directory.

Now, I am having trouble in making it work with the project. I am unable to build it using instructions online.

Error it generates is:

Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'Hrup' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I have included files like, build.gradle for all folder, and settings.gradle

[image: This is the project structure]

Build.gradle (volley)

```
// NOTE: The only changes that belong in this file are the definitions
// of tool versions (gradle plugin, compile SDK, build tools), so that
// Volley can be built via gradle as a standalone project.
//
// Any other changes to the build config belong in rules.gradle, which
// is used by projects that depend on Volley but define their own
// tools versions across all dependencies to ensure a consistent build.
//
// Most users should just add this line to settings.gradle:
//     include(":volley")
//
// If you have a more complicated Gradle setup you can choose to use
// this instead:
//     include(":volley")
//     project(':volley').buildFileName = 'rules.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        compile project (':volley')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
}

apply from: 'rules.gradle'

dependencies {

}
```

Build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bali.hrup"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Build.gradle(**Hrup**{my project name})

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':volley'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a Small Change, Edit the file build.gradle(app), not the build.gradle(volley)

Just add a single line

```
    compile project (':volley')
```

Final file(build.gradle(app)) will look like:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bali.hrup"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project (':volley')
}
```

Comment: I think after you git clone as Google documentation, copy `android` folder inside `\src\main\java\com` into `\app\src\main\java\com` of your project. No need to update `build.gradle` file anymore :)

Comment: What does that mean? Which android folder are you talking here?

Comment: the first path is of Volley project that you cloned as guided from Google https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Volley itself is imported as an android project. But, thanks for the suggestion.